# Python imap Lib

Tags: python, imap

Where can I find a complete description of all imap4 functions; especially with the  possible  parameter option and the return values and/or the data some of the functions create?  The http://docs.python.org/dev/library/imaplib just lists all the functions but not their possible parameters and the data they may create.

Answer (score 4):

The imaplib module is really a thin wrapper around the IMAP4rev1 protocol, and expects you to know pretty much all the ins and outs of that. The protocol is described in [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) (although imaplib was actually written against the now-obsolete [RFC 2060](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2060).) There are a few less... esoteric IMAP4 implementations for Python, like the one in [`twisted.mail`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedMail), which are a lot less painful to work with.

Answer (score 0):

@thomas-wouters is correct to point to RFC3501, but there are many extensions.

Here's a couple of more extensive lists:

- http://www.imapwiki.org/ImapRFCList
- http://networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/imap.htm